# Black screen after bios, safe mode works fine

Tags: windows-10, black-screen-of-death

Ryzen 7 3800X 
MSI mpg x570 gaming edge WiFi
Nvidia rtx 2080
Corsair vengeance RGB pro 32gb 3600mhz
Sabrent rocket 1tb m.2
Samsung 860 Evo 1tb
Rm 850x
Asus rog strix XG32V

This is a new build and my first build.

Pc boots up and displays bios splash screen and then goes black, keyboard, mouse and monitor remain on whereas they would normally sleep if no image was being received.

I was able to load into Windows when I first installed and it displayed normally for maybe a minute or less, I believe I saw a pop up in the bottom right corner saying something about display adapter before screen going black. Now I just get black after bios splash.

I am able to boot into safe mode with no issues as far as I can tell, tried updating GPU driver and monitor driver which hasn't worked, also tried doing a clean slate boot but had the same issue.

Also I haven't been able to activate windows yet and don't believe I can in safe mode.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Do you have a powerful enough PSU? And  did you connect the additional power cable to the GPU?

Comment: Yes, as in the question i stated i have a RM 850X and yes i connected the additional power cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a picture in normal mode by uninstalling the graphics card in device manager and then restarting the computer. this didn't work on the first restart but after a second restart windows recognised there was an issue and disabled the GPU and replaced it with a basic display adapter which at least gave me picture. The graphics card ended up being faulty after going through nvidia support trying to troubleshoot.